# Best Approach to handle exception in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception

Can any one tell me what is the best to handle exception in iOS (Objective C)?

I have the following two approaches:

1. Use try/catch block.
2. Do proper data handing for all model class.

What do you suggest?

Comment: This question is too vague really. Do you have any specific use cases or any specific issues?

Comment: This is a general question, If we have some thing wrong from json, like in json we get NULL value inside array/ dictionary etc

Comment: Apple has dropped exception handling in Swift. Guess why ? ;-)

Comment: Code defensively. Make no assumptions.

Comment: Three years never used a try catch block

Comment: @rmaddy defensively means.. not getting your point

Comment: After parsing your JSON, don't assume the dictionaries/arrays contain specific types of values. Check for `NSNull` objects, for example. If you get any exceptions it is because your code is making bad assumptions.

Comment: For typical "best practice" no most people do not use try/catch in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions in Objective are only meant to be used for programming errors where there is no recovery (the app will terminate immediately).

Exception are not designed to be used for program control flow in Objective-C. Check for all possible errors and handle them at that point.

Further, there is no cleanup on catches across stack frames so full recovery is generally not possible.

Comment: "fun recovery"? Did you mean "full recovery"? I like the idea of "fun recovery" though. :)

Comment: Oops, yes full, fixed, thanks! @rmaddy you should know by now that I am a bad speller, worst typer and combining that with auto-correct is a recipe for disaster. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, you should fix whatever is causing the exception. NSError is for errors that are expected (e.g. Backend returns invalid or not data). Exceptions are usy programming errors and should be fixed. Avoid try/catch, except when it is explicitly stated you should use it (e.g. Subclassing NSOperation).